# (Where) Can I ask questions about the content of design and programming books?

Tags: discussion, questions, books

Is there an appropriate place to ask questions about the content of a book I'm reading? I'm currently reading a book about object-oriented analysis and design where the authors derive some diagrams spontaneously with no explanation. I would like some clarification from others who have read the book. What I'd like to do is ask for clarification on diagram `x` in chapter `y` of the book. Is there any stack exchange site where a question like this is appropriate?

Answer (score 4):

> I would like some clarification from others who have read the book.

Questions that require someone to have read a specific book are too narrow for Stack Overflow.

> What I'd like to do is ask for clarification on diagram x in chapter y of the book.

Don't ask questions that reference particular diagrams in certain chapters of a book.  Instead, include the diagram and all of the required information in your question.  It's perfectly fine to ask for clarification on what an author was talking about, but you need to include enough information in your question to make it answerable by people who are knowledgeable in on the topic without having read that specific book.

Comment: Thanks. This may be a stretch, but you wouldn't happen to know if there are any copyright issues with submitting text and images copied directly from a book? I'm sure I could paraphrase the necessary contents, but it may remove so much context that it renders the question unanswerable.

Comment: @reallythecrash If you're only copying one diagram from a book to ask for clarification, it should be protected under fair use.  About a page of content is the most I would copy without paraphrasing before I would start worrying. (Naturally, always cite the source.)